# getting Wrong FS: file while running hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

while running a simple select query on hive I'm getting this weird error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://usr/lib/hive/lib/CustomUDFint.jar, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:207)
```

on googling I found all the links mentioning that the hive metadata for the the table location is pointing to some wrong place.

Any reason why this is so ? and How I can fix it?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure HADOOP_HOME is set to proper value?Which Hadoop release are you using?Try setting NN's location through Hive shell and see if helps :

```
hive -hiveconf fs.default.name=localhost
```

Change **localhost** as per your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the same problem, in my pom.xml I needed to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```